# Несовместимость слайд шоу и вкладок из-за  jquery.min.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Ребята, у меня на сайте не уживаются два эффекта: это слайд шоу и вкладка в нижнем правом углу по динамичной перемене backgraunda. Яблоком раздора стал эта ссылка на ява файл.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

который питает работоспособность кнопок слайд шоу, без него они просто не переключаются. Но в тоже время, когда он подгружен перестает работать вкладка по перемене фона. Как устранить эту несовместимость, ибо НЕ хочется подбирать другое слайд шоу или отказываться от вкладки по перемене фона. Я так понимаю, вся проблема в Java скрипте вкладки. А я в java ничего не смыслю. Без него никуда и с ним ни как =)

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="ru"><head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://1hd.com.ua/plc/menu.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

    <!------Fon---END--->    
<!--slide !-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://1hd.com.ua/plc/style.css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<!--slide end !-->
</head>
   <body>
<div class="container">
       <div class="wrapper1">
                <div id="ei-slider" class="ei-slider">
                    <ul class="ei-slider-large">
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/large/1.jpg" alt="image01" />
                            <div class="ei-title">
                                <h2>Креативно</h2>
                                <h3>Geek</h3>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/large/2.jpg" alt="image02" />
                            <div class="ei-title">
                                <h2>Дружественно</h2>
                                <h3>Devil</h3>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/large/3.jpg" alt="image03"/>
                            <div class="ei-title">
                                <h2>Спокойно</h2>
                                <h3>Compatriot</h3>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/large/4.jpg" alt="image04"/>
                            <div class="ei-title">
                                <h2>Неуверенно</h2>
                                <h3>Hussler</h3>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/large/5.jpg" alt="image05"/>
                            <div class="ei-title">
                                <h2>Сердечно</h2>
                                <h3>Rebel</h3>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/large/6.jpg" alt="image06"/>
                            <div class="ei-title">
                                <h2>Терпеливо</h2>
                                <h3>Seeker</h3>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/large/7.jpg" alt="image07"/>
                            <div class="ei-title">
                                <h2>Безмятежно </h2>
                                    <h3><a>Serenely</a></h3>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul><!-- ei-slider-large -->
                    <ul class="ei-slider-thumbs">
                        <li class="ei-slider-element">Текущий</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Слайд 1</a><img src="images/large/1.jpg" alt="thumb01" /></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Слайд 2</a><img src="images/large/2.jpg" alt="thumb02" /></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Слайд 3</a><img src="images/large/3.jpg" alt="thumb03" /></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Слайд 4</a><img src="images/large/4.jpg" alt="thumb04" /></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Слайд 5</a><img src="images/large/5.jpg" alt="thumb05" /></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Слайд 6</a><img src="images/large/6.jpg" alt="thumb06" /></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Слайд 7</a><img src="images/large/7.jpg" alt="thumb07" /></li>
                    </ul><!-- ei-slider-thumbs -->
                </div><!-- ei-slider -->

<!-- Вот он виновник jquery.min.js сего праздника, если его отключить, то кнопки слайдшоу не будут переключать фото, если включить, то вкладка в нижнем правом углу прекратит свою дееспособность. -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js1/jquery.eislideshow.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js1/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             $(function() {
                $('#ei-slider').eislideshow({
                    animation           : 'center',
                    autoplay            : true,
                    slideshow_interval  : 3000,
                    titlesFactor        : 0
                });
            });
        </script>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Начало выдвижной вкладки-->

 <div class="menuCon"style=" background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);">

            <a class="slider" style="background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);">
            <img alt="" id="top" src="http://1hd.com.ua/plc/arrow_top.png"></a>
            <ul id="nav">
                <li><a class="bg-switcher" value="1" href="#"><img width="20" height="20" src="images/bg1.JPG" /></a></li>
                <li><a class="bg-switcher" value="2" href="#"><img width="20" height="20" src="images/bg2.JPG" /></a></li>
                <li><a class="bg-switcher" value="3" href="#"><img width="20" height="20" src="images/bg3.JPG" /></a></li>
                <li><a class="bg-switcher" value="4" href="#"><img width="20" height="20" src="images/bg4.JPG" /></a></li>
                <li><a class="bg-switcher" value="5" href="#"><img width="20" height="20" src="images/bg5.JPG" /></a></li>
                <li><a class="bg-switcher" value="6" href="#"><img width="20" height="20" src="images/bg6.JPG" /></a></li>
                <li><a class="bg-switcher" value="7" href="#"><img width="20" height="20" src="images/bg7.JPG" /></a></li>
                <li><a class="bg-switcher" value="8" href="#"><img width="20" height="20" src="images/bg8.JPG" /></a></li>
                <li><a class="bg-switcher" value="9" href="#"><img width="20" height="20" src="images/bg9.JPG" /></a></li>
                <li><a class="bg-switcher" value="10" href="#"><img width="20" height="20" src="images/bg10.JPG" /></a></li>
                <li><a class="bg-switcher" value="11" href="#"><img width="20" height="20" src="images/bg11.JPG" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://1hd.com.ua/plc/js/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://1hd.com.ua/plc/js/jquery.easytabs.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Виталий Деревянко, перенесите код на [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 2):

Jquery подключен 2 раза....

1й

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2й

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://1hd.com.ua/plc/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

это скорее всего и вызывает конфликты, уберите нижний, скорее всего поможет

Comment: @Jquery не вызывает конфликтов сам с собой. Вот если бы был подключен prototype.js  - в таком случае да - там рушиться механика.

Comment: я как то сталкивался с такой проблемой когда было подключено 2 джиквери, вроде бы всё работало но анимация сбоила постоянно и не срабатывали колбеки, вобщем скорее всего это похожий случай

Comment: @crashik, согласитесь, что если 2 раза один и тот же файл подключен будет, то существующее определение заменится на само себя же и всё будет по-старому? Частные случаи, кстати, зависят от многих факторов. То есть, `вроде бы всё работало но анимация сбоила постоянно и не срабатывали колбеки` можно списать на кривизну и скрип кода. Не считаете?

Comment: если да кабы... тут не видно одинаковая ли версия... а код был нормальный

Comment: @crashik, видно - одна [1.7](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js), дургая - [1.3.2](http://1hd.com.ua/js/jquery.min.js). Где он такую откопал я понятия не имею.

Comment: причём более старый подключается позже нового... вобщем походу всё из за этого наверно.

Comment: @crashik, старая не подключается - там путь прописан, но файл лежит в директории выше

Comment: Ребята эврика я только что нашел выход из проблемы сам=)) если у кого-то тоже такая же проблема то уберите все ссытки на старые  рсии библиотеки джыквери у меня в частности 1,7  1,3,2 и поставте новую она есть на официальном сате джиквери.ком http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js  все проблемы исчезли мигом я доволен как слон. Как всегда решение проблемы настолько элементарно и до ужаса смешно. логика спасет верстальщика))

Answer (score 0):

Ребята, нашел выход из проблемы. Это до ужаса смешно. Как я не догадался до этого раньше. Мои версии jQuery давно уже устарели. Зашел на официальный сайт, скачал [новую](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js) и все работает как часики.

Логика спасет верстальщиков.